# jQuery cookies not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to use cookies with jQuery in my website, but nothing is happening at all.

This is my HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

I am trying to check if a cookie has been set - if it has, then use that value, if not, create a new one. This is my jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){

/* Using jQuery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie */
/* Check value of cookies */

var light = $.cookie("light-color");
var dark = $.cookie("dark-color");

if (light == null) {
    $.cookie("light-color", "#0095FF");
    var light = $.cookie("light-color");
}
if (dark == null) {
    $.cookie("dark-color", "#0068B3");
    var dark = $.cookie("dark-color");
}

changeColor(light, dark);

function changeColor(l, d) {

    $.cookie('light-color', l);
    $.cookie('dark-color', d);

    $('.site_color').css({"color":l});
    $('#nav #on').css({"color":d});

}

});
```

However, no cookies are being set because light and dark are not being set. What is going wrong?!

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Wait, how can we help you if you don't post the relevant code you are using? So which is the code you are using? Post relevant HTML markup too. Here your code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/631cyqre/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use `var` one time per variable. Remove it from your null checks. When you use it in the null checks, the scope of the variable means the outer ones don't change.

Move the changeColor function outside of the $(function() {} block.

Make sure you have cookies enabled in your browser.

```
$(function(){

    /* Using jQuery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie */
    /* Check value of cookies */

    var light = $.cookie("light-color");
    var dark = $.cookie("dark-color");

    if (light == null) {
        $.cookie("light-color", "#0095FF");
        light = $.cookie("light-color");
    }
    if (dark == null) {
        $.cookie("dark-color", "#0068B3");
        dark = $.cookie("dark-color");
    }

    changeColor(light, dark);
});

function changeColor(l, d) {
    $.cookie('light-color', l);
    $.cookie('dark-color', d);

    $('.site_color').css({"color":l});
    $('#nav #on').css({"color":l});
    $('#menu_dropdown #on').css({"color":d});
}
```

Comment: Try moving the changeColor function outside of the ready block. It works for me.

Comment: Tried that too, but that doesn't fix it. It still doesn't seem to ever set the light and dark variables or any cookies??

Comment: Did you check to see if you have cookies set? I use Web Developer Toolbar and it shows I have both cookies. `light-color: %230095FF`. If your cookies are being set and the color isn't working, that's a different issue.

Comment: It's a Firefox Addon. If you don't have it, use your browser to view your cookies. If that doesn't work, open a console (F12) and type `console.log($.cookie('light-color'));`. Make sure you check to see if cookies were really set in some manner.

Comment: Okay, it says `undefined` so they're just not being set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65104/discussion-between-mts7-and-user2397282).

Comment: Have you disabled cookie on your website or clearing cache between each tests? Doesn't this jsFiddle work on your side? http://jsfiddle.net/631cyqre/ In fact your code is correct, issue comes from somewhere else